# Symfony : how to "dynamically" generate a (big) form based on another (big) form?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I'm building a website that needs to have public forms where the fields are not statics, and based on the result of a form in the back office. So the only purpose of the back-office form is to specify which fields will be displayed in the related front-end form.

For example, imagine that i have an "Events" entity, with a related "eventsType". This form contains fields like a choiceType "activities" and so on, and is used in the back-office by the admin for creating an event. When this form is submitted, a new event is created.

The page displaying the new event also display a form where each fields is created dynamically based on this "events" data. 
This new form is bound to another entity, let's say "Attendees" and people can use this form to register to the event, submitting all the data specifics to this event (using the dynamically generated fields).

For now the only solution i have in mind for that is using the form events, but is there another way? I know there is some bundles out there for related problems like multi-step forms, but is there a bundle which could be used in my case?

Comment: Sorry, but questions asking for "What is the best way to..." are not well suited for StackOverflow. Your form is very dynamic I would recommend delegating this to your frontend logic and then only push the data to the backend (Symfony). With Serializer and Validator you can ensure the data is valid (or return errors as json) and then save the data. When using Symfony Forms you will probably end up writing the dynamic logic twice in the front- and backend which might not be ideal, plus it's difficult. Feel free to ask specific questions once you decided on an approach and run into problems.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, i will modify the question, in order to know the "classic way" of doing. But I don't understand why i would need to delegate this to the front end logic, as there is clearly two steps, involving two different actions, two different page and two different kind of user?

Comment: You could pass options from your controller to the formType and based on those options render the right fields.

Comment: You don't have to delegate it all to the frontend, but it will likely make it easier. Your form needs to know about all possible event types. At the same time you will have to duplicate this in the frontend for rendering. So you end up managing the display logic twice. If you skip the form and only deserialize the data and validate it, you don't have to care about managing all options, you only check if the current one works. This will keep the backend simple, decoupling it from the rendering options, and will make it easier to change things as you only have to change them in one place.

Comment: It is possible to do with Forms, but (generally speaking) does not work well for dynamic data. For example [adding new objects with fixed properties to a collection](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html) already requires a lot of work and dynamic properties make it worse. Not using Forms decouples  the backend data & logic from the display logic (and form rendering). You don't even have to use JS to process this data, you can also pass it to twig and create a static form based on the provided data as well.

Comment: Ok, i start to understand what you mean @dbrumann, i'll give it a try! Thanks a lot